# Discord.py Command raised an exception: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'miembros' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, discord.py

estoy haciendo un bot de discord, pero en un comando este error sale: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'miembros' referenced before assignment`

las únicas pruebas que hice fue borrar la variable y crearla de vuelta pero fue en vano.

El código esta en en repl.it: https://repl.it/@ticua07/qBot#main.py

PD: uso flask y threads para que el servidor de repl.it no se cierre mientras tiene el bot corriendo, y el comando donde tira error es golpe (funcion golpe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo en tu codigo, el try/except debieses invertir lo que hay dentro, debido a que en la linea 113 tienes "miembros" en el try y no está definida.
Y recien creas el array miembros[] dentro del except.

Así que debieses voltear lo que hay en el try: con lo que está en el except

Y remplazar en la condiciones que tienes tus "if" por un "if not" o "!=".

```
@bot.command(name="piña")
async def golpe(ctx, persona=""):
  try:
    if persona != "":
        guild = ctx.guild
        miembros = []
        for i in guild.members:
            if not i.bot:
                miembros.append(i)
            else:
                pass
        user = choice(miembros)
        a = choice([1,1,1,1,2,2,3])
        #...

  except:
    del miembros
```

Comment: Funciona, Gracias ^^!